# How can I implement pinch/zoom event to my canvas?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I've added a Canvas to my xaml page and drawn some squares on it. Now I want a event that allowes me to to zoom the canvas in and out, making the squares on it bigger and smaller.

I'm guessing I have to loop thru the children of the canvas and do the math magic on them, but how can I detect the user doing a zoom with two fingers? Does not seem to be anything built in?

Does anyone know about a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [manipulations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff898416.aspx). They are the representation of multitouch input in .Net, such as zoom, rotation and so on. You will have to work with 3 events :

- [ManipulationStarted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationstarted(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ManipulationDelta](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationdelta(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ManipulationCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationcompleted.aspx) (used for inertia)

With the `ManipulationDelta`, you will get a delta that you can use to transform your controls according to user's actions. Here is the MSDN Documentation

You will be interested by the `DeltaManipulation.Scale` property for your zoom.